# In Perl, how can I watch a directory for changes?

Tags: perl, filesystems, change-notification

```
use Text::Diff;
for($count = 0; $count <= 1000; $count++){
   my $data_dir="archive/oswiostat/oracleapps.*dat";
   my $data_file= `ls -t $data_dir | head -1`;
   while($data_file){
      print $data_file;
      open (DAT,$data_file) || die("Could not open file! $!");
      $stats1 = (stat $data_file)[9];
      print "Stats: \n";
      @raw_data=<DAT>;
      close(DAT);
      print "Stats1 is :$stats1\n";
      sleep(5);
      if($stats1 != $stats2){
         @diff = diff \@raw_data, $data_file, { STYLE => "Context" };
         $stats2 = $stats1;
      }
      print @diff || die ("Didn't see any updates $!");
   }
}
```

Output:

```
$ perl client_socket.pl
archive/oswiostat/oracleapps.localdomain_iostat_12.06.28.1500.dat
Stats:
Stats1 is :
Didn't see any updates  at client_socket.pl line 18.
```

Can you tell me why the stats are missing and how to fix it?

Comment: I don't believe that's the code you actually ran. $data_file would have contain the name of the file followed by a newline, so open would fail, so it would die. A `chomp` would fix that. There's numerous other problems, but what's the point of commenting on something that's not your code? I strongly recommend you start by adding `use strict; use warnings;` and fix those errors.

Comment: it has file, as you see it printed in the fist line as "archive/oswiostat/oracleapps.localdomain_iostat_12.06.28.1500.dat"

Comment: No, it has `"archive/oswiostat/oracleapps.localdomain_iostat_12.06.28.1500.dat\n"`

Comment: @ikegami, it is the actual code.  On my Linux system, according to strace, `open(F, "newline\n")` calls `open("newline" *[sic]*, ...)`, but `stat "newline\n"` calls `stat("newline\n" *[sic]*, ...)`.  You're right, it's newline trouble.  Three-arg open appears to preserve the newline, FWIW.

Comment: so what is the fix then?

Comment: @pilcrow, Interesting. VeeraMarni, lack of `chomp`, as previously mentioned, is the first error.

Comment: @ikegami, see Q&A linked from my (updated) answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note that I'm answering your original question, why the `stat()` seemed to fail, rather than the newly edited question title, which asks something different.*

This is the fix:

```
my $data_file= `ls -t $data_dir | head -1`;
chomp($data_file);
```

The *reason* this is the fix is a little murky.  Without that `chomp()`, `$data_file` contains a trailing newline:  `"some_filename\n"`.  The two argument form of `open()` [*ignores* trailing newlines in filenames <strike>and I don't know why</strike>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11253450/132382) because two-arg open mimics shell behavior.  Your call to `stat()`, however, does not ignore the newline in the filename, so it is `stat()`ing a non-existent file and thus `$stats1` is `undef`.

Comment: @picrow thans for the help. I m touching perl after a long time, thanks for quick help. And i need to correct the $stats2 which is in the if loop. This variable should be global, how should i correct this. As of now stats2 is showing empty.

Answer (score 14):

The real fix is [File::ChangeNotify](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::ChangeNotify) or [File::Monitor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Monitor) or something similar (e.g., on Windows, [Win32::ChangeNotify](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::ChangeNotify)).

```
use File::ChangeNotify;

my $watcher = File::ChangeNotify->instantiate_watcher(
    directories => [ 'archive/oswiostat' ],
    filter => qr/\Aoracleapps[.].*dat\z/,
);

while (my @events = $watcher->wait_for_events) {
    # ...
}
```

Comment: +1: Sinan: I need this functionality and I think your post helps me.